# Get maximum value for SQL DateTime in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I could swear there's a property somewhere in SqlClient to do this, but both my Google-fu and IntelliSense have abandoned me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SqlDateTime.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.maxvalue%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Which, for future reference, is in System.Data (which is why going to SqlClient is a dead end) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that this value is found in `System.Data.SqlTypes`.